# file is not empty however python outputs the file as empty in list form?

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to access the contents of a file in list form, I try that and the file returns empty, it wont recodnise breaklines and the file is definitly not empty can anyone explain this...

```
   with  open("scores.txt","a+") as filescores: 

        scores=list(filescores)
        print(scores)
```

output:
[]

thanks!

Comment: The use of `filescores` is fine. It'll be a list of lines by default. You can use those functions to specify what you want.

Comment: @Moinuddin The duplicate seems misdirected; the problem here is the file mode, as the current answer suggests. `list(filehandle)` will indeed iterate over `filehandle` and read in the lines into a list.

Comment: @nagyl `list(file scores)` would be the idiomatic approach, file objects are iterators over lines. `readlines` is a fossil

Answer (score 1):

Have a close look at the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.

To **r**ead a file, you use `open("scores.txt","r")`. `a` is for **a**ppending.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) [mode](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) of `a+` The file has been opened for appending and therefore, the file pointer is at the end of the file. The `+` allows the file also to be read, but read from where? From the end!

Easy to demonstrate.

First, create a file:

```
from pathlib import Path 

p=Path('/tmp/file')

with open(p, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([str(e) for e in range(10)]))
    # file will be '0\n1\n2\n'...
```

Now open that file with `a+` mode:

```
with open(p, 'a+') as f:
    l=list(f)

>>> l
[]
```

`l` is empty because `f` is at the end of the file. Easy to change too:

```
with open(p, 'a+') as f:
    f.seek(0)        # reposition the file pointer to the start of file
    l=list(f)

>>> l
['0\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '6\n', '7\n', '8\n', '9']
```

Or, just use the `r` for read mode and the file pointer will be at the start of the file:

```
with open(p, 'r') as f:
    l=list(f)
# ['0\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '6\n', '7\n', '8\n', '9']
```